# Zero-inflated Poisson distribution parameter estimates

Tags: confidence-interval, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

Let's say we have a population distributed by Zero-inflated Poisson distribution:

$$ f(x | \psi, \lambda) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  1-\psi + \psi e^{-\lambda}  & \mbox{if } x = 0 \\
  \psi \frac {\lambda^x e^{-\lambda x}}{x!} & \mbox{if } x > 0
 \end{array}
\right.
$$

and then a sample with size $N_s$ and known parameters $\psi_s$ and $\lambda_s$.

How can I estimate the confidence intervals for the parameters $\psi$ and $\lambda$?